# convolution continuity

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity, convolution

can someone help me with this exercise:

Let there f and g be 1-periodic functions both in ${L^2([0,1))}$ . Show that the convolution $$(f*g)(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)g(y) \,dy$$ is well defined for all x and that it is 1-periodic and continuous in R.

I have proven that it is well defined and 1-periodic. All i want is some hint as to why it is continuous. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The definition is wrong. The integral over the whole line need not exist.

Comment: @Dimitris Should the integral be over $[0,1]$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integral is meant to be over $[0,1]$, it suffices to note that
$$
|(f*g)(x_1) - f*g(x_2)|^2 = \left|\int_{[0,1]} (f(x_1-y) - f(x_2 - y))g(y) \,dy\right|^2\\
\leq \left(\int_{[0,1]} |g(y)|^2 \,dy\right)
 \left|\int_{[0,1]} |f(x_1-y) - f(x_2 - y)|^2 \,dy\right|,
$$
then use the continuity of the shift operator $f(x) \mapsto f(x - a)$ as a linear map over $L^{2}([0,1])$.